# Snap CI initialize-android.sh Permission denied

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I created a initialize-android.sh script to configure my pipeline as recommended here: https://docs.snap-ci.com/the-ci-environment/languages/android/

But everytime the job run I got an Permission denied when trying to run the script.

I already tried running as ./initialize-android.sh and ${SNAP_WORKING_DIR}/initialize-android.sh

The SNAP_WORKING_DIR is right, because the log is:
bash: line 57: /var/snap-ci/repo/initialize-android.sh: Permission denied

Someone knows if I need to configure some kind of permission to execute my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am part of the SnapCI team. It looks like the initialize-android.sh  script does not have executable from repository itself.
I would suggest you to change the file permission and commit the changes. You should be able to run the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe that the error message could a little more helpful, permission denied did not make me think that the problem could be that it could not be executed.